# Unable to retrieve included objects from Parse.Query

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I'm having an issue regarding Parse.Query and how to break down the result promise it. This is currently my code:

```
var ga = new Parse.Query(Game);
ga.include('away_team');
ga.include('home_team');
ga.equalTo("objectId", req.params.id);
ga.find().then(function(result){
  console.log(result[0]);
});
```

That console log outputs something like this:

```
{
  "home_team" : {"name":"Dallas Stars", "arena":"American Airlines Center"},
  "away_team" : {"name":"New York Rangers", "arena":"Madison Square Garden"},
  "createdAt" : "2015-12-28T10:35:35.541Z"
}
```

My problem is, how can I get the name from `away_team` inside my promise function? If I change the console.log line to `console.log(results[0].createdAt)`. My console outputs
`2015-12-28T10:35:35.541Z` as intended. But if I change that line further to `console.log(results[0].away_team)` my console logs *No message provided*.

Which apparently is wrong, in my world *(inside my head)* it would've returned
`{"name":"New York Rangers", "arena":"Madison Square Garden"}`

But okay, fine, I don't really need that line but what I need is to retrieve the name from it. When I try the following line: `console.log(results[0].away_team.name)`
I get an error saying **Result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

I can do this (results.away_team.name) within my .jade template if I send it to view with JSON.serialize() and in my view parse it with JSON.parse(). If I try doing this in my router class, I get either **Unexpected u token in ...** or **Unexpected o token in ...**

My goal is to send a correct title to my view depending on the home and away team in the current game I am browsing like below:

```
res.render('inside/game', {
  title: result[0].away_team.name + " vs. " + result[0].home_team.name
  // title: New York Rangers vs. Dallas Stars
});
```

Am I trying to work something out that is not intended to work within the routing class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the find is a parse object, not JSON. Your workaround is taking that object and converting it, via JSON text, to plain JS objects, which isn't great but does work.

Parse objects can't access most content directly because they don't have explicitly defined methods for arbitrary keys. Instead you need to use the `get` function.

```
result[0].get("home_team")
```

And you can chain a subsequent request for the `name` or store the result to a var so you can unpack multiple pieces of data efficiently.

Comment: Fantastic! I think I've finally learned that what something looks like isnt always what something really is!